# JQuery UI : Drag/Drop : Deal with several containers and overflow property

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable

Firstly, I made a JS fiddle to explain my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/QvRjL/59/

I am completely stuck on a drag and drop problem:

- I want always have the dragging element visible above my containers
- I need to be able to drag the yellow boxes located in the cells of the "**containerB**" from row 1 into one of the cells of the row 3 for exemple.
- I need to be able to drag the yellow boxes located in the cells of the "**containerA**" to the row 3 of the "**containerB**"

When I apply the property `AppendTo : 'body'` : the yellow boxes are always visible over all my containers, but it is not possible to reach the "row3" of the "**containerB**" because of the auto-scroll is not working on this container

When I apply the `AppendTo : '#container'` property : the auto-scroll of the "**containerB**" is enabled but the yellow boxes are not visible above the "**containerA**"

My constraints are that all the cells must have the property "overflow" because the cells can have plenty of yellow squares.

Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figure it out using using `appendTo : 'body'` to view the `clone` over all containers and check the drag position of my scrollable `container B` to create a `setInterval` function to simulate the scroll.

Here is my fiddle updated : http://jsfiddle.net/QvRjL/66/

Any comment or advice are welcome!